# ByteChannel not uploading text file

Tags: java

My program has to upload a text file chosen by the user. I wrote this function:

```
void UploadToDatabase() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
          URL website = new URL("http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/test.txt");

          WritableByteChannel rbc = (WritableByteChannel) Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/recfile.txt");

          fos.getChannel().transferTo(0, Long.MAX_VALUE, rbc);
     }
```

I have an error because the IDE tells me that "java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl cannot be cast to java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel".

How could I fix this problem? I call the function in this way: (NetBeans suggested it to me too)

```
try {
            UploadToDatabase();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(xGrep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(xGrep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this.

```
URL website = new URL("http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/test.txt");

WritableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openConnection().getOutputStream());

FileOutputStream fos;
fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/recfile.txt");

fos.getChannel().transferTo(0, Long.MAX_VALUE, rbc);

fos.close();
```

Comment: Does this upload "recfile.txt" on my server? +1

Comment: You have a FileOutputStream("C:/recfile.txt"), so I believe you are writing it to that location. "C:/recfile.txt"

Comment: No, I just want to upload that "recfile.txt" on a server. I don't need to write anything inside it :)

Comment: Updated. Give that a try.

Comment: It works! :) I'd like to ask you another thing: I have this error now "cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)". What should I type? (Answer accepted btw)

Comment: Great! Can you create another question and I'll check it out. It'll be easier to understand the problem if you can write it out and show us where you're getting an error.

Comment: Add the link in these comments so I know you created it, also it could be a reference for someone in the future who stumbles across this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932694/cannot-write-urlconnection-because-of-dooutput also, thank you for being very disponible :)