# Cannot write URLConnection because of doOutput

Tags: java

I've asked a question here and I've fixed my problem thanks to an user. This is the code I am using at the moment.

```
void UploadToDatabase() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
          URL website = new URL("http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/record_file.txt");
          WritableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openConnection().getOutputStream());

          FileOutputStream fos;
          fos = new FileOutputStream("record_file.txt");
          fos.getChannel().transferTo(0, Long.MAX_VALUE, rbc);
          fos.close();
     }
```

My goal is upload the file `record_file.txt` on a particular web link as you can see above. However, when I try to run this code, NetBeans gives me this error:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)
```

I read some stuff about this and I added the following code just after the declaration of that `rbc` variable.

```
 URLConnection urlc = website.openConnection();
 urlc.setDoOutput(true);
```

By the way, I always have the same error. Could you help me?

Comment: You are going to need to pass `urlc.getOutputStream()` to `Channels.newChannel()`.

Comment: could you show me how to do it? With the code

Comment: I'll put that in an answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem lies on this line:

```
WritableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openConnection().getOutputStream());
```

You will need to set `doOutput` to `true` for this to work. Here's how:

```
URLConnection urlc = website.openConnection();
urlc.setDoOutput(true);
WritableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(urlc.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: +1 :) now I'm having another error like "java.nio.channels.NonReadableChannelException". Do you know how could I fix it?

Comment: @tbodt you're missing something :/

Comment: @AlbertoRossi tell us what then

Comment: I know. I think it is that the output stream on the url connection is not the correct output stream to be using. To make this work, you would put a script on the server that wrote what it recieved on input for the "text" parameter to a file specified by a GET parameter.

Comment: so you mean that I could write a small php file with a $_GET[] ?

Comment: Yes. It would retrieve a get parameter, then open the corresponding file, then write everything that came from standard input to that file. I don't know much about this, so you may have to use a post parameter instead of standard input.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was due to incorrect way of using header, like

```
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity("parameters", headers); //Issue was here
```

I just made as

```
 HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity(headers); //Fixed Issue
```

check [here](https://javaerrorandsolution.blogspot.com/2018/08/caused-by-javanetprotocolexception.html) other details

Answer (score 0):

I am a Java programmer and I have a different solution. Maybe this will be useful for someone.
Just have a look at your advanced **proxy settings** in your web browser. 
System engineers in our company had changed the **proxy settings** but I was not aware of it.
This error cost me 3 work-days. I got this **doOutput** error while writing a ftp upload project in my company. I tried everything like adding `conn.setDoOutput(true)` or 'fifty shades' of similar solutions but non of them saved me. 
But, **after I changed my proxy settings** to correct ones, the error dissapeared and now I am able to upload my files through ftp using urlConnection in java. 
I used the code in the link below to make an upload process, and did not add anything except host, port, user and password.
http://www.ajaxapp.com/2009/02/21/a-simple-java-ftp-connection-file-download-and-upload/